# Google Maps Autocomplete this.setValues is not a function

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, maps

Trying to get Autocomplete working. Set up a test page, just HTML and JS, but still getting the "this.setValues is not a function" error. Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="place">

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API-KEY&libraries=places"></script>

    <script>
      var place = document.querySelector('#place');
      console.log(place);
      var dropdown = google.maps.places.Autocomplete(place);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's the error:
[image: this.setValues is not a function error]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi NotoriousWebmaster,

I believe that the problem is that you didn't use the "new" keyword when defining the dropdown variable.  Try this: `var dropdown = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(place);`

Comment: d'Oh! You'd think I'd pay closer attention to things like that.